# listBoxFor not sending values back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, razor

I'm trying to choose several options from a given and send the chosen ones back to the controller.

[The view (image) is something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyDHT.png)

The problem I have is that the values are not send back to the controller. I can move the items from one `ListBox` to another though.
The code is as it follows:

View

```
....
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.participantes, Model.participantes.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.nombre, Value = x.id.ToString() }), new { id = "listBoxSeleccionados", style = "width: 180px; height: 200px; resize: none;" })
....
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.posiblesparticipantes, Model.posiblesparticipantes.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.nombre, Value = x.id.ToString() }), new { id = "listBoxPosibles", style = "width: 180px; height: 200px; resize: none;" })
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{
    ....
    prueba.posiblesparticipantes = Pers.listaPersonaParticipantes();
    prueba.participantes = new List<ModeloPersona>();
    return View(prueba);
}

public ActionResult Create(createCurso_prueba model, FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class createCurso_prueba
{
    ....
    public List<ModeloPersona> posiblesparticipantes { get; set; }
    public List<ModeloPersona> participantes { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Comment: You cant bind a select to a collection of complex objects. The properties you bind to need to be `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<int>` etc. And in future include only the code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!! That was it!